# Find a baseline from Image containing Arabic Text

Tags: image-processing, ocr, aforge, baseline

How can I find baseline from image containing Arabic Text:

[image]

I have tried with histogram (vertical and horizontal) but unable to find generic code which can give me absolute value.

Comment: I have made family group of different arabic characters and based on that I am taking Vertical histogram value and then dividing the lower portion of each word. This works for me :)